# regex For Flight no and Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following string

```
XX1366**A**Monday 5 November 2018XX4515**B**Monday 5 November 2018XX3416**C**Monday 17 December 2018XX1744**D**Tuesday 18 December 2018
```

Want to extract the data in below format:

**Flight No :**  `XX1366,XX4515,XX3416,XX1744`

**Flight Date :** `Monday 5 November 2018, Monday 5 November 2018, Monday 17 December 2018, Tuesday 18 December 2018`

**My Code :** `A, B, C, D` (which is after the Flight No)

Could you help me to extract this data using regular expression?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit laggy but should work, you can adapt it easily :

```
(XX[0-9]+)([A-Z])([a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]+ [a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]+)
```

Pleas note that you can always test your regex online at sites like https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1):

Surely not the most elegant solution, however the following works too:

```
XX(\d*)(\w)(\w*\s\d+\s\w*\s\d*)
```

As a sidenote in case you're wondering - people on the website are far more likely to answer your question if you have put in some effort beforehand. Basically it's a forum for coding help, rather than on-demand code-writers. :)

Answer (score 0):

On option could be to use 2 capturing groups to match either XX followed by 4 digits or match any character and use a positive lookahead to assert that what followed is XX followed by 4 digits or the end of the string `$`

Then while looping the matches collect the values in an array and use join to show them comma separated.

`(XX\d{4})\*\*[A-Z]\*\*|(.*?(?=XX\d{4}|$))`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tg64Cm/1)

```js
const regex = /(XX\d{4})\*\*[A-Z]\*\*|(.*?(?=XX\d{4}|$))/g;
const str = `XX1366**A**Monday 5 November 2018XX4515**B**Monday 5 November 2018XX3416**C**Monday 17 December 2018XX1744**D**Tuesday 18 December 2018`;
let m;
let flights = [];
let flightDates = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  if (m[1]) {
    flights.push(m[1]);
  }
  if (m[2]) {
    flightDates.push(m[2]);
  }
}
console.log("Flight No: " + flights.join(','));
console.log("Flight Date: " + flightDates.join(', '));
```

Or you might use a combination of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to create a multidemensional array where the first value is for example `XX1366` and the second `Monday 5 November 2018` and you could extract those values. First split on the positive lookahead `(?=XX\d{4})` and then split on matching `\*\*[A-Z]\*\*`

```
const str = `XX1366**A**Monday 5 November 2018XX4515**B**Monday 5 November 2018XX3416**C**Monday 17 December 2018XX1744**D**Tuesday 18 December 2018`;
let res = str.split(/(?=XX\d{4})/)
    .map(x => x.split(/\*\*[A-Z]\*\*/)
    );
```

```js
const str = `XX1366**A**Monday 5 November 2018XX4515**B**Monday 5 November 2018XX3416**C**Monday 17 December 2018XX1744**D**Tuesday 18 December 2018`;
let res = str.split(/(?=XX\d{4})/)
  .map(x => x.split(/\*\*[A-Z]\*\*/));

console.log("Flight No: " + res.map(x => x[0]).join(', '));
console.log("Flight Date: " + res.map(x => x[1]).join(', '));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex can help you :

**Flight No** : `(XX[0-9]+)` 
**Flight Date** : `[MTWFS][a-z]+ [0-9]{1,2} [a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]{4}`
**Code** : `(?<=\*)([A-Z])`

You can use `/y` flag to match at last Index.